# A probability problem

Tags: probability, self-study

When a bike is broken, it is brought to the warehouse. The average time spent at the warehouse for repair is 7 days. On average, a bike gets one fault every 100 rides. A fault costs 10 euros to repair. The total rides for a month are 10,000 and the total bicycles are 300.

How many bikes will get fault in next month & what will be the cost to repair them?

Background - I was asked this problem during an interview for a micromobility company where they gave me these numbers & also revenue (0.8 euros/ride =8000 euros) & cost numbers (2000 euros without repair costs). Finally i had to answer how will the faulty bikes impact the revenue and overall cost?

I dont really know how to tackle this problem as i believe there may be some missing information or i am just too dumb. Would be great if someone can help.

Comment: Can you share what you’ve done as well?

Comment: Thanks for the context. It's open-ended and you're expected to make assumptions. Pretty common in job interviews.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'll give it a try. There could be mistakes though I'm my logic.

So total rides for a month are 10,000. On average there's a fault after 100 rides. So there'll be 10000/100 = 100 faults.

Each fault costs 10€ to repair, so (10€)×(100 faults) = 1000€

Assuming all 300 bikes are in working condition, so 300 - 100 = 200 working bikes for the month. This is a simple assumption that all bikes are working at the start of the month, in reality there could be less than 200 active bikes or more than 200 active bikes.

Total revenue = 8000 - 2000 (costs no repair) - 1000 (repair costs) = 5000€